# How do I make VPN connection working from Azure VM?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have created Virtual Network Connection.
I have created Connection for Site to Site(IPSec) which connects to VMWare-snx
Connection status is "Connecting". (Also connection from VMWare SNX side)
I have VM in subnet. VNet is same as with Gateway Subnet.
I try to ping or RDP to VM in VMWare side, but do not have connection.

Did I understand correctly that I should have automatically connection from all subnet in VNet.
No routing is needed between Gateway Subnet and others?

Is there any way to troubleshoot if ping passed Azure VPN?

https://vzerotohero.com/2017/03/step-by-step-deploy-vmware-nsx-with-microsoft-azure-ipsec-vpn-site-to-site/

Answer (score 0):

If the VPN connection is set up well, the Connection status should be "connected". Please follow the step by step in the [article](https://vzerotohero.com/2017/03/step-by-step-deploy-vmware-nsx-with-microsoft-azure-ipsec-vpn-site-to-site/), especially the note things:

- NSX VPN as of now only supports **Policy-Based** VPN type.
- PFS: Disable Perfect Forward Secrecy since its not supported with Azure **Static-Policy based** VPN.

[image]